# loading initial page of jquery mobile app using worklight platform

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, ibm-mobilefirst

this is worklight application developing for cross platform, when i start the application i need the default page to appear, i've used jquery mobile for developing pages which are placed under same html file...

```
<html>
<body>
<div data-role="page1" id="one">
.
.
</div>
<div data-role="page2" id=two>
.
.
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

inside the wlCommonInit() function i'm trying to load first page like this

```
function wlCommonInit(){
$.mobile.changePage("#one");
}
```

currently the result page is not what i expected, it loads both pages with each page element overlapping on each other...How to load initial page defined in same html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at the jQuery mobile application sample on Worklight's developer works site - http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/WorklightStarter_jQueryMobile.zip

Comment: replacing the jquery.mobile.js from head to body did the trick